# Blank document returned from URI in C# HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponsemessage

I am trying to write a method for an API in ASP.NET which will take an id, and return a document from a URI.

Once the documents are downloaded, they are either blank or do not contain the correct characters.

The method in my controller is as follows:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("document/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDocumentFor(string id)
    {
        string documentURI = "http://example.com/id=" + id;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(documentURI);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);

        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();;
        var contentLength = data.Length;

        var dataStream = new MemoryStream(data);   

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "test.pdf";
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;

        return httpResponseMessage;
}
```

I have tried a similar approach using WebClient, as well as other strategies provided in various forum posts. Each gave similar results.

Any comments or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the response contains the expected document, and not something else like HTTP error markup?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I do believe so. If I experiment with the Content-Disposition header, I can see the correct filename. Additionally, the documents have the correct page count.

If I use a URI for a document of type "file", it is successfully converted to a PDF and displays the right information. The problems are most notably occurring with .pdf and .doc files (even if the ContentType and ContentDisposition.Filename values are changed accordingly).